# How do I make the top image not transparent so the background image doesn't show through?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, overlay

I have a UIImage view and then an overlay and then another UIImage view. I need the top UIImageView to not be transparent at all. I don't want to see any of the background image.

I have tried setting alpha, I have tried using blend processer with Kingfisher, I have tried converting the png to a jpg, I have tried moving one subview in front of the other, I have tried changing the background colors of the images, I have tried setting the top image to opaque and not opaque as I read different things, I have tried so many things.

```swift
 clientProfileImg.borderWidth = 2.0
 clientProfileImg.borderColor = UIColor.white
 clientProfileImg.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
 clientBackgroundProfileImg.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
 view.bringSubview(toFront: clientProfileImg)
 view.sendSubview(toBack: clientBackgroundProfileImg)
 clientProfileImg.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

 clientProfileImg.alpha = 1.0

  guard let profilePic = client?.profilePhoto else { print("No profile pic"); return }
  let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: profilePic)!, cacheKey: profilePic)
  // Blend (iOS)
  // let processor = BlendImageProcessor(blendMode: .sourceAtop, alpha: 1.0, backgroundColor: .black)
        // Set the image to Kingfisher which caches it
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.clientProfileImg.kf.setImage(with: resource, placeholder: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user-gray"), options: [.forceRefresh, .cacheSerializer(FormatIndicatedCacheSerializer.jpeg)])
      self.clientBackgroundProfileImg.kf.setImage(with: resource, options: [.forceRefresh,
                                                      .cacheSerializer(FormatIndicatedCacheSerializer.jpeg)] 

  }
```

Here is what I see:
[image: what is happening]

Here is what I want:
[image: what i want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it, actually there was an overlay image between them in the storyboard. removing that and programmatically adding it at runtime fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

try to use the method

### withRenderingMode(_:)

Three rendering mode values..

```
.automatic (default)
.alwaysOriginal
.alwaysTemplate
```

Comment: i solved it, actually there was an overlay image between them in the storyboard. removing that and programatically adding it at runtime fixed this issue.